# PCRE Youtube Iframes

Tags: php, regex, iframe, youtube, htmlpurifier

I'd like to know if, given iframe code for a Youtube video such as the following:

```
<iframe width="500" height="315"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/v/somevid" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

If it's possible to devise a regex that identifies width, height, theme, and video details (just the "v/somevid" part). Here's the trick: I'd like to do it regardless of the position of these attributes, in a reliable manner.

The purpose is for a better version of the YouTube Filter for HTMLPurifier, which will grab supplementary elements as well as just the video information.

I have been trying to come up with this, but I can't seem to make it work regardless of position.

Comment: yes its possible, so write some code

Comment: I've been trying out a bunch of ways on http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester but nothing that I do ends up working despite positionality of those attributes.

Comment: Can you help me with it?

Comment: To do such stuff reliably you really should use a HTML parser.